# How do you cast an Angular instance element into a jQuery object?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Inside of the linking function, you have access to the instance element. How do you cast this into a jQuery object?

```
.directive('responsiveHeight', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, iEl, attrs) {
        iEl.bind('', function() {       // what event to do this on?
          scope.$apply(function() {
            var width = $(iEl).width();
            $(iEl).css({'height': (width/1.77) + 'px'});
          });
        });
      }
    };
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular comes with jqLite, but if you include the jquery script before angular, angular will use your full version of jquery instead.  So in the link function, iEl will be a jquery object.

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible because different  DOM